# Quarto - how to define data frames in document

Tags: r, quarto

I'm trying to render multiple data frames in a Quarto document, and while I'm able to execute the code in the code blocks, trying to render gives me this error:

```
processing file: hello.qmd
  |..........................................          |  80% (unnamed-chunk-2)Quitting from lines 29-38 (hello.qmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'df' not found
Calls: .main ... stop_if_not_gt_tbl -> is_gt_tbl -> gt -> <Anonymous>
```

How would I define "df" in Quarto? I've tried the following below;

````
```{r}
df %>% gt() %>%
  tab_header(title = "Title") %>%
  data_color(
    columns = c('0':'12'),
    palette = c("yellow","orange","red")
  )
```
````

Here is what I have in the R file: `data_for_df <- df`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example - it makes it much easier for others to help. Share the document, including where you define `df` within the document. (Remember that data frames need to defined in the Quarto document somehow - they don't get read in from your global environment).

Comment: I see, I changed the question to account for that information.

Comment: Assuming that `df` is a data frame - how did you create the data frame in the first place? Add that code to the Quarto document. (If you create a reproducible example, it's easier for us to help when you share what you've already tried in your Quarto document).

Comment: In the edited question, `df` already exists. The data frame must be created somewhere. Does your Quarto document `source` an Rscript or `load` data to the environment? If not, there needs to be some code chunk that makes `df`, i.e. contains `df <- ...`.

Comment: How would I source an Rscript or load data into the environment? I apologize for the stupid questions, still very new to Quarto.

Comment: You'd use the `params` section of the YAML header.  See [this](https://www.jhelvy.com/posts/2023-02-28-parameterized-pdfs-with-quarto/), for example.  Another way of passing a `data.frame` as a parameter that isn't mentioned in that post is to pass the _name_ of the data frame as a parameter and then `get` the data.frame itself in the script.  Alternatively, save the `df` in an Rds file, pass the filename as a parameter and then read the file in the document.

Comment: Try `source("Your_Rscript_file.R")` (where the definition of `df` lies) in a code chunk before the chunk where you want to use the `df`